# ArcGIS 10.1: Subtype/Domain Functionality

Tags: arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, domains

Is there any way to create more complex conditional domains in a table than a single subtype and associated domains? I would like to get the same functionality that more than one subtype in a single table would provide but ArcGIS only allows one. I want to be able to use multiple domains in one field that are part of a subtype, where each domain might only allow other domains used in the next field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where your idea fits in among these, but there are several out on the [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com/) site you might want to vote for:

1. [Allow subtypes on multiple fields](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008HuSAAU)
2. [Requesting a Sub-Subtype Option](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008DzIAAU)
3. [Coded value domains set mulit-level dependancy on coded value domains for a feature class](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008820AAA)

Comment: That's pretty much what I want to do. Subtypes are so handy. I just wish there wasn't the limit.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is ancient, but ArcGIS Pro has functionality called Contingent Values that might be what you need:

> [Create and manage contingent values](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/contingent-values.htm)
>
> Contingent values, sometimes referred to as contingent attribute
> values, are a data design feature that allows you to make values in
> one field dependent on values in another field.

Alternatively, [attribute rules](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/an-overview-of-attribute-rules.htm) might be useful too.